# Upgrading existing app to iOS 6

Tags: ios6

while compiling/upgrading one of my existing apps to iOS 6 beta 4, it's crashing on device, however with simulator it's working fine.If anyone has tried it before, that will be really helpful.

Here is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: CC4112AC-DB73-489B-A64D-C946B6B25422
CrashReporter Key:   ea874c1da9152b46ac359400c82fdc7f548b1778
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         AppCatalogue [2248]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9E3C6AAF-7341-42AF-B1DE-875F3B7A5555/AppCatalogue.app/AppCatalogue
Identifier:      AppCatalogue
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-08-08 11:03:46.526 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A5376e)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3674d6be 0x3668b000 + 796350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x389c697a 0x389be000 + 35194
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36751222 0x3668b000 + 811554
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3674f94c 0x3668b000 + 805196
4   CoreFoundation                  0x366a7464 0x3668b000 + 115812
5   AppCatalogue                    0x0000a2aa 0x1000 + 37546
6   AppCatalogue                    0x0000aa12 0x1000 + 39442
7   UIKit                           0x38167b7c 0x38119000 + 322428
8   UIKit                           0x3814c936 0x38119000 + 211254
9   UIKit                           0x38163e12 0x38119000 + 306706
10  UIKit                           0x3811ff26 0x38119000 + 28454
11  QuartzCore                      0x3546de96 0x3546a000 + 16022
12  QuartzCore                      0x3546da34 0x3546a000 + 14900
13  QuartzCore                      0x3546e970 0x3546a000 + 18800
14  QuartzCore                      0x3546e34e 0x3546a000 + 17230
15  QuartzCore                      0x3546e15c 0x3546a000 + 16732
16  QuartzCore                      0x3546dfbc 0x3546a000 + 16316
17  CoreFoundation                  0x36722ae8 0x3668b000 + 621288
18  CoreFoundation                  0x36720ddc 0x3668b000 + 613852
19  CoreFoundation                  0x36721132 0x3668b000 + 614706
20  CoreFoundation                  0x36694398 0x3668b000 + 37784
21  CoreFoundation                  0x36694224 0x3668b000 + 37412
22  GraphicsServices                0x35049316 0x35044000 + 21270
23  UIKit                           0x381708f4 0x38119000 + 358644
24  AppCatalogue                    0x0003052a 0x1000 + 193834
25  AppCatalogue                    0x00002e54 0x1000 + 7764
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to narrow down the error and post some code. No one can help you with such a general problem.

Comment: That will certainly help

Comment: What is the code doing that matches frames 5 and 6?  ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html )

Comment: @PhillipMills do you mean AppCatalogue ?

Comment: I mean the specific parts of it that are on the stack and which call into the CoreFoundation library.  The link I provided should tell you how to find out what they are.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I'm going through the link.I will keep posting after symbolicating the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build/run with xCode 4.5 GM. Some troubles was fixed in my case.

Comment: Hey @Merc thanks!! I just downloaded yesterday, got to check it today :)